# Creating a MySQL view issue

Tags: mysql

As part of a university project, I'm designing a Star Wars game.

Part of what I need to do is whittle down characters based on certain attributes.  I had originally used a massive MySQL query to get what I needed, but I advised that by using views, I can make like a lot easier for myself.  However, I've run into an issue.

For example, below is the original MySQL query to display all the characters who do not use a lightsaber:

```
-- Query where person does not use a lightsaber --
select * from person, weapon, person_weapon
WHERE person.id = person_weapon.person_id 
AND person_weapon.weapon_id = weapon.id and weapon.name != "Lightsaber"
AND person.name NOT IN (select person.name from person, weapon, person_weapon 
WHERE person.id = person_weapon.person_id 
AND person_weapon.weapon_id = weapon.id and weapon.name = "Lightsaber");
```

This returns the relevant characters eliminates the rest.  I wanted to put this into a view that could be queried again.  So I created this:

```
CREATE VIEW noLightsaber AS 
SELECT alias, class, force_wielder, gender, image, name AS p_name, pilot, quote, species,
colour_id, how_many, name AS w_name, person_id, weapon_id from person, weapon, person_weapon
WHERE person.id = person_weapon.person_id 
AND person_weapon.weapon_id = weapon.id and weapon.name != "Lightsaber"
AND person.name NOT IN (select person.name from person, weapon, person_weapon 
WHERE person.id = person_weapon.person_id 
AND person_weapon.weapon_id = weapon.id and weapon.name = "Lightsaber");
```

It was recommended to use name AS something_name as both a person and a weapon have a name.  However, it's erroring.  I'm getting an #1052 error - Column "name" in field list is ambiguous.  Obviously it's due to name appearing in 2 tables, but I'm unsure how to progress this.

Comment: First of all, please, please, please use modern join syntax, available since SQL-92, that's 28 years ago.

Comment: A long time ago, in a galaxy far away, we stopped using comma joins and the evil `SELECT death star`. Come, JOIN us.

Answer (score 0):

The ambiguity for column name must be solved using the tablename which the column is related; in your case you should use `person.name AS p_name`.

```
CREATE VIEW noLightsaber AS 
SELECT alias
  , class
  , force_wielder
  , gender
  , image
  , person.name AS p_name
  , pilot
  , quote
  , species
  , colour_id
  , how_many
  , person_weapon.name AS w_name
  , person_id
  , weapon_id 
from person
INNER JOIN person_weapon ON person.id = person_weapon.person_id 
INNER JOIN weapon ON person_weapon.weapon_id = weapon.id and weapon.name != "Lightsaber"
WHERE person.name NOT IN (
  select person.name from person, weapon, person_weapon 
  WHERE person.id = person_weapon.person_id 
  AND person_weapon.weapon_id = weapon.id and weapon.name = "Lightsaber"
);
```

And you should use explicit join syntax.

Comment: Thanks.... with regards to using outdated ideas.... I'll feed that back to my tutor. I hadn't touched MySQL before September, so have been using his lecture notes as guidance.